# CKSubscription error iOS10

Tags: swift, push-notification, swift3, xcode8, ios10

My subscriptions were working properly with iOS 9, but since I updated, I have a very odd error. I have two subscription methods that are equal, except for the fields they manage. Here is the code:

```
let meetingSubscriptionPredicate = Predicate(format: "Users CONTAINS %@", (id?.recordName)!)

let meetingSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Meetings", predicate: meetingSubscriptionPredicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

let notification = CKNotificationInfo()
notification.alertBody = "Meeting Created!"
notification.shouldBadge = true
notification.accessibilityPerformEscape()
meetingSubscription.notificationInfo = notification

database.save(meetingSubscription) { (result, error) -> Void in
       if error != nil {
             print(error!.localizedDescription)
       }
}

let universitiesSubscriptionPredicate = Predicate(format: "Name = %@", self.UniversityTextField.text!)
let universitiesSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Universities", predicate: universitiesSubscriptionPredicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
let universitiesNotification = CKNotificationInfo()
universitiesNotification.alertBody = "Your university is now on Meet'em!"
universitiesNotification.shouldBadge = true
universitiesNotification.accessibilityPerformEscape() 
universitiesSubscription.notificationInfo = universitiesNotification
database.save(universitiesSubscription, completionHandler: { (saved, error) in
       if error != nil {
             print(error!.localizedDescription)
       }
       else {
             print("University subscription created")
       }
})
```

The odd thing is that the Meeting subscription is saved, and the University's subscription is not. I've double checked the names and they are all right at the Dashboard. Besides that, I'm not getting any notification on my phone when supposed to...

Comment: facing same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found elsewhere online that you can try to reset your development environment. In my case, the predicate I was trying to use was not set to queryable. This is ticked where you define your record type. The reason it worked one day and not another is possibly due to moving from development to production. At that time you are asked to optimize indexes, and it is possibly here that the ability to search on a given predicate is dropped. That seemed to be the case for me anyway.